# Adding a firewalld service using firewall-cmd

Tags: linux, configuration, linux-networking, firewalld

How do I create a new service for firewalld from the commandline programmatically?

I cannot find an option to firewall-cmd that allows me to do this. Am I just missing it or does it actually not exist? In case of the latter, is there another option? I know that you can create a .xml service file, but I am looking for a cleaner (less error prone) way to create a service file.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this FedoraForum thread](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?p=1730933), it can't be done at the moment.

However, in the very same thread, [this post](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?s=eb2789dc8ed7f1590ad8faa37f3ace98&p=1730933&postcount=5) explain a possible workaround using a python script importing firewalld bindings.

In short:

```
python -c "import firewall.core.io.service as ios
s=ios.Service() #Creates a service object
s.short = 'My Matlab Service' #A short description
s.name = 'matlab' #this defines the name of the xml file
s.ports = [('1234', 'tcp'), ('12345', 'udp')] #A list of ports
ios.service_writer(s, '/etc/firewalld/services')"
```